# How can i apply a filter in this avro schema using Apache Flink

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink, kafka-consumer-api

Hello guys i'm deserializing an Avro Kafka message like this:

```
FlinkKafkaConsumer<String> consumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer("conekta.public.person",
     new KafkaGenericAvroDeserializationSchema("http://localhost:8081"), kafkaProps);
```

the messagge i'm getting is like this:

```
{"before": null, "after": {"id": 257, "status": "c4ca4238a0"}, "source": {"version": "0.9.4.Final", "connector": "postgresql", "name": "conekta", "db": "testdb", "ts_usec": 1579909929965704, "txId": 5847, "lsn": 294339488688, "schema": "public", "table": "person", "snapshot": false, "last_snapshot_record": null, "xmin": null}, "op": "c", "ts_ms": 1579909930004}

{"before": null, "after": {"id": 258, "status": "c4ca4238a0"}, "source": {"version": "0.9.4.Final", "connector": "postgresql", "name": "conekta", "db": "testdb", "ts_usec": 1579910374459669, "txId": 5849, "lsn": 294473695272, "schema": "public", "table": "person", "snapshot": false, "last_snapshot_record": null, "xmin": null}, "op": "c", "ts_ms": 1579910374518}
```

How could i apply a filterto get all the records where the id is < 258 on my flink consumer.

I'm very new in Apache Flink.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `boolean isEndOfStream(GenericRecord nextElement)` on the KafkaGenericAvroDeserializationSchema to return true when you want the stream to end.